# Anaconda Breaks Python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Just installed Anaconda distribution and now any time I try to run python by double clicking a script, or executing it in the command prompt (I'm using windows 10) , it looks for libraries in the anaconda folder rather than my python folder, and then crashes. If I run via the command prompt, I'm able to see the error, which is:

> File "C:\Users\bob\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py",
>   line 19, in
>
> "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>
> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

I've uninstalled and re-installed Python and numpy multiple times, but it's getting installed in the default python folder, and since I installed the anaconda distribution, the python launcher always looks in the Anaconda folder. I have to run modules from IDLE or not at all.

Is there any way to get Anaconda to play nice with the standard python installation? I'd really like to be able to quickly and easily double click python scripts to run them.

Comment: Please let me know if you somehow fix this issue, I am also facing the same. What I can think of is uninstalling anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with pip , you should not need a separate installation. If you need a library not available in anaconda then you would use pip. Both will store your downloaded packages in site-packages. In your scripts folder you should have [usually only one] reference to python. Generally I think anaconda is the preferred repository. I would **consider** removing " standard installation". If you need two for some reason make sure only one is in your environment variable path. Assuming you don't have the anaconda version in your path; go to the scripts folder ,in the cmd prompt and type 
python myscript.py